# Truncated in time derivation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have follogwing equations:

$E(n) = \frac{1}{2} ||\vec{\epsilon}(n)||^2$

with

$\vec{\epsilon}(n) = \vec{y}_{target}(n) - \vec{y}_{prediction}(n) $

where n denotes a discrete time. $\vec{y}_{prediction}(n) $ gets calculated the following way:

$\vec{y}_{prediction}(n) = W_{o}.[\vec{x}(n), \vec{u}(n), 1]$

Here [;] is the concatination and $\vec{x}(n)$ is calculated by

$\vec{x}(n) = \tanh{(rW.\vec{x}(n-1) + W_{in}\vec{u}(n))} $

where r is an scalar and $\vec{u}(n)$ is an Inputvector.
Now I want to calculate the derivative

$\partial_r E(n) = -\epsilon^T(n),W_o(n).[\partial_r\vec{x}(n);0_u]$

$\partial_p\vec{x}(n) = ...$

with Mathematica. Here $0_u$ is a vector with the same length as $\vec{u}$ but every entry just 0. This would be theoratically $n$ times the chain rule, but I want to truncate it to just one derivative.

Is all of this possible at all?